# importing "Module 'app_settings'" not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

I'm currently trying to work with xcode to test my flutter application with xcode. The big issue is that all of my imports (such as app_settings, cloud_firestore, etc...) give an error for "Module ___ not found". When I try to run my dart code I get the error in the terminal:

```
[Proj Root]/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'app_settings' not found
@import app_settings;
~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
```

I tried running flutter create for ios, (this might've made things worse?) Flutter clean and reinstalling pods doesn't seem to work either. I'm wondering if there's something simple that I missed with importing modules. I created the application on android using modules that should work with Android & iOS. After getting the android version working I pulled my project on my mac through github and finally reached this issue. Any pointers would be appreciated because I'm totally stuck on this.

Comment: did you find the solution? This works on my iPhone but not on the simulator

Comment: Yeah, the solution for me was to delete the Pods file and do Flutter run -> flutter pub get. Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm Not sure what happened but it seems to be good now. I think `pod init` was initializing minimal data for the podfile. Instead, I deleted the Pods file and did flutter run and it built the podfile correctly with `flutter pub get`.

Comment: Hey, I tried everything but not working, actually, I am on M1, so you got any solution for me?

Comment: The only solution I had was the clear out all the old pods files and have flutter rebuild them with flutter run -> flutter pub get Hope that helps

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, we solved it by setting the iOS Deployment target in XCode to the same value as set in the `Podfile`, which was `12.0`. Then ran `flutter clean` and `flutter build ios` worked like a charm

Answer (score 4):

1. Delete pod directory and podfile.lock
2. flutter clean
3. flutter pub get
4. cd ios
5. pod install --repo-update
6. run the application in Xcode

Answer (score 3):

My project has 3 build flavor. Development, Staging & Production.

In Xcode It was selected default Runner One. (On Top of the middle)

though i follow the process like

- delete pod , Podfile.lock and .symlinks from Android Studio / (From Project)
- flutter pub get
- cd ios > pod install
- Then In XCode > clean build
- Select Right Build Flavor (Production For Me)
- Then Archive (Done)

NB: I tested in M1 machine.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem. What I did was

1. Delete the Podfile and Podfile.lock
2. `flutter clean`
3. `flutter build ios`
4. Opened the Runner.xcworkspace
5. Build on Xcode

This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything above, but for me the solution was quite different.

I am using flavors (schemes), and I accidentally created the scheme with upper case in the first character, while everywhere else (build config etc.) I used lower cases only. After deleting the scheme and recreating with lower case characters, it worked.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31982819)

Comment: I did not misname my schemes, however deleting and recreating them did the work

Answer (score 1):

My issue was I had opened the xcodeproj instead of the xcworkspace

Opening and building the **xcworkspace** fixed this for me

Answer (score 0):

```
path/flutter/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9: Module 'app_settings' not found
```

I had the same issue after upgrading the Xcode to 13.3 and my production build flavor wasn't working. I was using firebase as well. In my production build flavor, I didn't append anything to the configuration name (i.e. all the other configurations have the name like "Debug-staging", "Debug-development", but in the production, it's only "Debug"). I just deleted the pod file and run:

[image]

> flutter run --flavor production --target lib/main_production.dart

Everything worked fine for me.