# Unable to import module app_setings in Xcode - Flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, apple-m1

I'm currently building a flutter application, which works perfectly in Android.
While trying building it on Xcode, I got one single error

> "unable to import module app_settings".

Build target is an IPad air 2020, with an M1 chip inside.

Is there any workaround?
Thank you

Comment: Hi. I would like to request you to maybe share your verbose output. Like the single error you shared doesn't help much in identifying the cause of the issue. It would be better to be able to see the entire error message with all the verbose. You can run `flutter run -v`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following steps in terminal:

1. flutter pub get
2. pod init
3. pod install

Here is the similar problem question answer @jstoe
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66235764/16585144

Answer (score 0):

deleted the Pods file and did flutter run and it built the podfile correctly with flutter pub get.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem with the M1 chip. Try to update your Mac OS and Xcode as well.